# Retrofit - removing some invalid characters from response body before parsing it as json

Tags: android, json, jsonp, gson, retrofit

I have an external web service that in the response body returns json but nested in parentheses, like this:

```
({"door_x":"103994.001461","door_y":"98780.7862376", "distance":"53.3"})
```

Using this code:

```
class AddressInfo {
    String door_x;
    String door_y;
}

interface AddressWebService {
    @GET("/reversegeocoding")
    AddressInfo reverseGeocoding(@Query("x") double x, @Query("y") double y);
}
```

It obviously fails. This is the stacktrace:

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:377)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
        at com.something.$Proxy7.reverseGeocoding(Native Method)
        at com.something.ReverseGeocodingService.getAddress(ReverseGeocodingService.java:24)
        at com.something.LocationProvider$1.run(LocationProvider.java:77)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
 Caused by: retrofit.converter.ConversionException: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
        at retrofit.converter.GsonConverter.fromBody(GsonConverter.java:67)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:362)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
            at com.something.$Proxy7.reverseGeocoding(Native Method)
            at com.something.ReverseGeocodingService.getAddress(ReverseGeocodingService.java:24)
            at com.something.LocationProvider$1.run(LocationProvider.java:77)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
 Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
        at retrofit.converter.GsonConverter.fromBody(GsonConverter.java:63)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:362)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
            at com.something.$Proxy7.reverseGeocoding(Native Method)
            at com.something.ReverseGeocodingService.getAddress(ReverseGeocodingService.java:24)
            at com.something.LocationProvider$1.run(LocationProvider.java:77)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:374)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:165)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
            at retrofit.converter.GsonConverter.fromBody(GsonConverter.java:63)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:362)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
            at com.something.$Proxy7.reverseGeocoding(Native Method)
            at com.something.ReverseGeocodingService.getAddress(ReverseGeocodingService.java:24)
            at com.something.LocationProvider$1.run(LocationProvider.java:77)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

What is the best way to remove the parentheses before parsing the json?

Comment: Apparently the server is a JSONP enabled server, but I have no way to avoid the parentheses wrapping

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can clean painlessly the response in your `GsonConverter` before `Gson` deserialized the body into type object.

```
 public class CleanGsonConverter extends GsonConverter{

            public CleanGsonConverter(Gson gson) {
                super(gson);
            }

            public CleanGsonConverter(Gson gson, String encoding) {
                super(gson, encoding);
            }

            @Override
            public Object fromBody(TypedInput body, Type type) throws ConversionException {
                String dirty = toString(body);
                String clean = dirty.replaceAll("(^\\(|\\)$)", "");
                body = new JsonTypedInput(clean.getBytes(Charset.forName(HTTP.UTF_8)));
                return super.fromBody(body, type);
            }
            private String toString(TypedInput body){
                    BufferedReader br = null;
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    try {
                        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(body.in()));
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line);
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (br != null) {
                            try {
                                br.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return sb.toString();

                }
        };
```

JsonTypedInput:

```
   public class JsonTypedInput implements TypedInput{

        private final byte[] mStringBytes;

        JsonTypedInput(byte[] stringBytes) {
            this.mStringBytes = stringBytes;
        }


        @Override
        public String mimeType() {
            return "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
        }



        @Override
        public long length() {
            return mStringBytes.length;
        }

        @Override
        public InputStream in() throws IOException {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(mStringBytes);
        }
    }
```

Here I subclassed `GsonConverter` to get access to the response before it is converted to object. `JsonTypedOutput` is used to preserve the mime type of the response after cleaning it from the junk chars.

Usage:

`restAdapterBuilder.setConverter(new CleanGsonConverter(gson));`

Blame it on your backend guys. :)

Comment: Nice, I didn't have the chance to test it yet. Just one question, how should I initialize the gson parameter passed to the CleanGsonConverter constructor?

Comment: Same as you do to GsonConverter. `new CleanGsonConverter(gsonBuilder.create())`

Comment: Thanks! it works. The only thing I needed to change was the regex because the original was replacing the whole text. I used "(^\\(|\\)$)"

Comment: Edit approved. Enjoy! :)

Comment: how to this with retrofit 2?

Comment: Do you have an Ide how to do this in retrofit 2? @Pedram

Answer (score 8):

## Solution For Retrofit 2

The code below is the same as the `GsonConverter` except you can edit the `Response` before converting to its model

Edit **`public T convert(ResponseBody value)`** to clean your `Response`

```
/**
 * Modified by TarekkMA on 8/2/2016.
 */

public class MyJsonConverter extends Converter.Factory {

    public static MyJsonConverter create() {
        return create(new Gson());
    }

    public static JsonHandler create(Gson gson) {
        return new JsonHandler(gson);
    }

    private final Gson gson;

    private JsonHandler(Gson gson) {
        if (gson == null) throw new NullPointerException("gson == null");
        this.gson = gson;
    }

    @Override
    public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations,
                                                            Retrofit retrofit) {
        TypeAdapter<?> adapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(type));
        return new GsonResponseBodyConverter<>(gson, adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public Converter<?, RequestBody> requestBodyConverter(Type type,
                                                          Annotation[] parameterAnnotations, Annotation[] methodAnnotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        TypeAdapter<?> adapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(type));
        return new GsonRequestBodyConverter<>(gson, adapter);
    }


    final class GsonRequestBodyConverter<T> implements Converter<T, RequestBody> {
        private final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        private final Charset UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

        private final Gson gson;
        private final TypeAdapter<T> adapter;

        GsonRequestBodyConverter(Gson gson, TypeAdapter<T> adapter) {
            this.gson = gson;
            this.adapter = adapter;
        }

        @Override
        public RequestBody convert(T value) throws IOException {
            Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(buffer.outputStream(), UTF_8);
            JsonWriter jsonWriter = gson.newJsonWriter(writer);
            adapter.write(jsonWriter, value);
            jsonWriter.close();
            return RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, buffer.readByteString());
        }
    }

    final class GsonResponseBodyConverter<T> implements Converter<ResponseBody, T> {
        private final Gson gson;
        private final TypeAdapter<T> adapter;

        GsonResponseBodyConverter(Gson gson, TypeAdapter<T> adapter) {
            this.gson = gson;
            this.adapter = adapter;
        }

        @Override
        public T convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
            String dirty = value.string();
            String clean = dirty.replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n" +
                    "<string xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">","").replace("</string>","");
            try {
                return adapter.fromJson(clean);
            } finally {
                value.close();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

- Another solution is to blame the inexperienced backend developer.

Comment: You have some typos: you need to replace "JsonHandler" with "MyJsonConverter" or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative regex to convert from jsonp (dirty) to json (clean):

```
String clean = dirty.replaceFirst("(?s)^\\((.*)\\)$", "$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Orginally answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59298779/8956093)

**For parsing invalid JSON or String or JSONP response, use ScalarConverterFactory.**

For parsing JSON response, use **GsonConverterFactory**.

If you use say flatMap to call JSON API followed by JSONP API then use both GsonConverterFactory(**needed for JSON**) and ScalarConverterFactory(**needed for JSONP**).

Make sure you have below dependencies in your gradle :

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
//For serialising JSONP add converter-scalars
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
//An Adapter for adapting RxJava 2.x types.
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0'
```

Add converterFactories to retrofit and use setLenient() while building Gson to get rid of error `JSON document was not fully consumed.`

```
val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://api.flickr.com/")
            .client(builder.build())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()) //important
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()

@GET("end-point/to/some/jsonp/url")
fun getJsonpData() : Observable<String>
```

Use converters to convert invalid JSON to JSON by removing prefix and suffix present.
And then convert the string to your data model via

```
SomeDataModel model = Gson().fromJson<SomeDataModel>(jsonResponse,
            SomeDataModel::class.java)
```

Comment: Alternative :  JsonObject