# Retrofit 2.0 addConverterFactory to replace &quot with "

Tags: json, parsing, android-studio, retrofit2, html-escape-characters

in my JSON string its contain &quot,

```
{"value":" &quot;Testing&quot;"}
```

If did not perform any convertion or replace of string, the default retrofit's parser doesn't take care of the escape characters, and i will have `&quot;` in my result, so I found code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290267/retrofit-removing-some-invalid-characters-from-response-body-before-parsing-it) that help me to remove the escape characters before the retrofit's parse process, here is the modification code

```
public class MyJsonConverter extends Converter.Factory {

public static MyJsonConverter create() {
    return create(new Gson());
}

public static MyJsonConverter create(Gson gson) {
    return new MyJsonConverter(gson);
}

private final Gson gson;

private MyJsonConverter(Gson gson) {
    if (gson == null) throw new NullPointerException("gson == null");
    this.gson = gson;
}

@Override
public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations,
                                                        Retrofit retrofit) {
    TypeAdapter<?> adapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(type));
    return new GsonResponseBodyConverter<>(gson, adapter);
}

@Override
public Converter<?, RequestBody> requestBodyConverter(Type type,
                                                      Annotation[] parameterAnnotations, Annotation[] methodAnnotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
    TypeAdapter<?> adapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(type));
    return new GsonRequestBodyConverter<>(gson, adapter);
}


final class GsonRequestBodyConverter<T> implements Converter<T, RequestBody> {
    private final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    private final Charset UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    private final Gson gson;
    private final TypeAdapter<T> adapter;

    GsonRequestBodyConverter(Gson gson, TypeAdapter<T> adapter) {
        this.gson = gson;
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public RequestBody convert(T value) throws IOException {
        Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(buffer.outputStream(), UTF_8);
        JsonWriter jsonWriter = gson.newJsonWriter(writer);
        adapter.write(jsonWriter, value);
        jsonWriter.close();
        return RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, buffer.readByteString());
    }
}

final class GsonResponseBodyConverter<T> implements Converter<ResponseBody, T> {
    private final Gson gson;
    private final TypeAdapter<T> adapter;

    GsonResponseBodyConverter(Gson gson, TypeAdapter<T> adapter) {
        this.gson = gson;
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public T convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
        String dirty = value.string();
        String clean = dirty.replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n" +
                "<string xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">","").replace("</string>","");

        clean = clean
                .replace("&quot;", "\"")\\This line!!!
                .replace("\\/", "/") ;

        try {
            return adapter.fromJson(clean);
        } finally {
            value.close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

when I execute this code, it will fail later in retrofit parsing code and throw me this error

> com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at
>   line 1 column 1121 path
>   $.entry_list[0].name_value_list.highlight1_c.value

I understand the meaning of this error, but what is the right way to do this? And I doesn't like to replace escape characters after the retrofit Parse the Json into POJO, because that will be a lot of messy replace everywhere. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

I make a mistake on this line of code, it should escape it with a backslash: before ".

```
.replace("&quot;", "\\\"")
```