# What does ' json response starts with a '/' character' means?

Tags: android, json

I've this link: https://git.io/fjaqJ

And this is some weird instructions: Please note that every json response starts with a '/' character. You need to parse it accordingly.

What does that mean? **Actually, using this json, I've to show data in stack cardview.**

I tried this(Should I directly paste this below class into my Android studio modal class? And why there is hashmap?):

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"id",
"text"
})
public class Datum {

@JsonProperty("id")
private String id;
@JsonProperty("text")
private String text;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonProperty("id")
public String getId() {
return id;
}

@JsonProperty("id")
public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

@JsonProperty("text")
public String getText() {
return text;
}

@JsonProperty("text")
public void setText(String text) {
this.text = text;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"data"
})
public class Example {

@JsonProperty("data")
private List<Datum> data = null;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonProperty("data")
public List<Datum> getData() {
return data;
}

@JsonProperty("data")
public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
this.data = data;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`"/"` Character might appear from converting to `String` format in Python. So they might using `Flask` for sending this `Json`. However, it's not a problem. just remove first element before parsing.

```
if (text != null && text.charAt(0).toString().equals("/")) {
    text = text.subString(1, text.length())
}
```

Comment: This is about java and android. There is no Python. Also I've to use this data into Android. How can I do this? I tried using this: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @PoojaSingh Your **SERVER** is using Python to return this `Json` String.

Answer (score 0):

Orginally answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59298779/8956093)

**For parsing invalid JSON or String or JSONP response, use ScalarConverterFactory.**

For parsing JSON response, use **GsonConverterFactory**.

Make sure you have below dependencies in your gradle :

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
//For serialising JSONP add converter-scalars
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
//An Adapter for adapting RxJava 2.x types.
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0'
```

Add converterFactories to retrofit and use setLenient() while building Gson to get rid of error `JSON document was not fully consumed.`

```
val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://api.flickr.com/")
            .client(builder.build())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()) //important
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()

@GET("end-point/to/some/jsonp/url")
fun getJsonpData() : Observable<String>
```

Use `converters or mappers` to convert invalid JSON to JSON by removing prefix and suffix present.
And then convert the string to your data model via

```
SomeDataModel model = Gson().fromJson<SomeDataModel>(jsonResponse,
            SomeDataModel::class.java)
```